# Material coloring doesn't work

Tags: c, opengl

I have created a room, actually rectangular with two windows and one door. I have been trying to light the matarials with their material properties. I have used the below code but it does not work; why?

NOTE: light is in the room, as expected

in myinit ()

```
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);


    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_AMBIENT, light[0]);  
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_DIFFUSE, light[1]);  
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_SPECULAR,light[2]);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_POSITION,light[3]);  // position of the light
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT1);
```

in draw room ()

```
   glMaterialfv ( GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT ,material[0] ) ;
   glMaterialfv ( GL_FRONT, GL_DIFFUSE ,material[1] ) ;
   glMaterialfv ( GL_FRONT, GL_SPECULAR ,material[2] ) ; 
   glBegin (GL_TRIANGLES); 
            glColor3f ( /*...*/ )             
            // ...
   glEnd ( ) ;
```

in main ()

```
   glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you enabled the lighting itself? Enabling just a light isn't enough, you should enable the whole light system as well (it's off by default)

It should happen in the initialization function:

```
glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
```

Also, don't forget:

```
glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
```

If you want material colors. (You have it now, but it's another little flag that can cause problems)

Another vital element one must understand in order to understand how lighting works in GL is [normals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_normal). For every vertex you have in your geometry, you must also tell OpenGL which way it's facing, so that it can calculate its direction relative to the light position, in order to determine how bright it should be. [This](http://www.cse.msu.edu/~cse872/tutorial3.html) looks like a decent introduction to the concept in OpenGL.

When I first started with OpenGL, I thought that these normals would be computed automatically from the given triangles. *I was wrong.* **OpenGL doesn't automatically compute the normals of a model**, even though, in theory, it could (albeit with blocky results - maybe smooth with more advanced techniques).

And another recommendation - it would be a good idea to avoid using **fixed pipeline** functionality such as `glBegin(...) ... glEnd()` blocks (also known as *immediate mode*). It's outdated and slow. Check out [this great tutorial series](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/) for a good introduction to modern techniques also used in modern games.

Comment: I did not do your first advice.By the way, I have edit my init part in question.

Comment: Are you setting the normals for each point? OpenGL needs the normals for the light computations.

Comment: Can you describe a bit more ? I do not understand how I can do that

Comment: The last question dow you know any tutorial or sample code about shadow mapping.

Comment: opengl-tutorial.org has a great shadow mapping tutorial here: http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-16-shadow-mapping/ But be warned, you need to know your way around the programmable pipeline really well first. Shadow mapping is an intermediate to advanced topic.

Comment: But, it uses other project or libraries. With only using opengl libraries, can I manage shadow mapping ?

Comment: Again, you can't simply jump into that tutorial without going through the prerequisites - you need some matrix and vector utilities, and that tutorial introduces them gently at the beginning.